# Allow bean implementation not to define arguments provided by getBean

Tags: spring, spring-bean

My application uses configuration file (parsed as `@ConfigurationProperties`) to start multiple network streams with different services/processors in them. A good analogy would be setting up Netty channel pipelines from external config.

YAML properties look like this:

```
streams:
- type: tcp-server
  port: 2000
  services:   # this is the tricky part
  - type: watchdogTimer
  - type: someFormatConverter
  - type: dbLogger
    options: 
    - table: "things"
```

I want services to be easily defined, created, and located. So I decided to use Spring as registry for them - they can be prototype-scoped Spring beans, `type` is Spring Bean name and they are created like this:

```
// Kotlin language
@Autowired
private lateinit var appContext: ApplicationContext

fun createStreamService(stream: MyStream, type: String, options:Map<String,String>): MyStreamService {
  return appContext.getBean(type, stream, options) as MyStreamService
}
```

My problem is that even if service doesn't need stream or options reference, I still must have them in constructor `(stream:MyStream, options:Map<String,String>)`. **Is it possible to supply arguments that might not exist in bean implementation signature?** I know you can make them optional in sense that the call site can not supply them, but what about the other way?

Answer (score 0):

In case there would be no better solution, I'm going to pass single object encapsulating all arguments (stream and options).

While still an enforcement of implementation constructor signature, it is more concise and leaves space for extension without breaking compatibility.